# Calculate median absolute difference using Crystal Reports 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a list of employees and turn-around times, like so:

```
order | employee | turn-around
------------------------------
1     | Mark     | 1
2     | Mark     | 2
3     | Mark     | 10
4     | John     | 1
5     | John     | 5
6     | John     | 20
7     | Chad     | 15
8     | Chad     | 20
9     | Chad     | 60
```

So, as you can see, the data ends to be skewed somewhat, and so I'd like to summarize each employee by their median turn-around:

```
employee | median turn-around
-----------------------------
Mark     | 2
John     | 5
Chad     | 20
```

I'd also like to present each employee with a comparison of how they're doing compared to the other employees. For this summary, I'd like to use the difference from the median of the medians:

```
employee | median turn-around | median absolute difference
----------------------------------------------------------
Mark     | 2                  | -3
John     | 5                  |  0
Chad     | 20                 | +15
```

I'd like to have this automatically done in Crystal Reports 2013 so each employee gets their own page with a histogram of their turn-around times, their median turn-around time, and how it compares to the median of all the other employees' median turn-around times.

Alas, my crystal-fu is failing me in the last part. I have grouped the records by employee, created a formula field to calculate the turn-around time in the details, and created a formula to retrieve the median turn-around for the employee in the group footer. I've managed to create my histogram. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to aggregate the group medians and report the median of that median without querying the same data again using a subreport. Is it possible to accomplish this without a subreport?

Comment: are they always going to be 3 records for employee?

Comment: alas no; there are on the order of 1500 entries per employee. I see where you were going, though, and it's clever!

Comment: I think that your best choice here is doing and stored procedure.